# Call a constant name from web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, namespaces, constants

In a webserivce coding, I want to call a constant name from web.config.
I have this code :

```
namespace Service.AppCode.Common.Service
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = Constants.Namespace)]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void DoWork();
    }
}
```

and this code:

```
namespace Service.AppCode.Common
{
    public class Constants
    {
        public const string Namespace = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaulIP"];
    }
}
```

it will say :

> The expression being assigned to
>   'Service.AppCode.Common.Constants.Namespace' must be constant

is it possible to call it from web.config?

Comment: You can't, a constant is set at compile time and a config file is read at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constants are defined at compile-time and embedded directly into the resulting code, they're not initialized when the application executes.  (And can't change, unlike a config value which very much can change.)

However, looking at this...

```
public class Constants
{
    public readonly static string Namespace = 
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaulIP"];
}
```

It looks like you just want a static immutable value.  That's easy enough...

```
public class Constants
{
    public static string Namespace
    {
        get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaulIP"]; }
    }
}
```

That would read the value dynamically from the configuration any time it's invoked.  And since it's only a getter, it's read-only.  If you want it to only read from the config once, just cache the value:

```
public class Constants
{
    private static string _namespace = null;
    public static string Namespace
    {
        get
        {
            if (_namespace == null)
                _namespace = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaulIP"];
            return _namespace;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is microsoft documenation on how to add an app setting. It includes how to setup the config file.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Also for a simple item like this app settings is fine, but app settings can get big quickly.  Depending on the complexity of the settings, you might want to consider using a config section.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3%28v=vs.140%29.aspx